# How to Unarchive NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Since we can not directly store NSArray in core data so I am storing an array of NSManagedObject into another NSManagedObject by converting the array into NSData. The NSManagedObject stored in that array are conforming to NSCoding protocol and I am implement methods of NSCoding protocol in those classes in order to archive them.

```
@implementation MyClass
   - (void)encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject: [self canPay] forKey: @"canPay"];
    [coder encodeObject: [self guestId] forKey: @"guestId"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

 if((self = [self init]))
     if (self)
     {
         [self setCanPay: [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey: @"canPay"]];
         [self setGuestId: [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey: @"guestId"]];
     }

    return self;
}
```

Saving array of MyClass as NSData using following lines of code

```
NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayContainingMyClass];
[myEntity setMyClassData:myData];
```

The problem is while unarcheiving myClassData, I am getting exception....

```
 NSData *newdata = [NSData dataWithData:myEntity.myClassData];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:newdata]];
```

In the second line I am getting exception,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyClass setCanPay:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x743c950'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `self = [self init]` in `initWithCoder:`, you need to call `self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]`. But even then I'm not sure that's going to work. Core Data manages its own objects (hence the name `NSManagedObject`), so I don't know if storing them yourself by means of `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` is going to end well for you.

Your best bet is to use Core Data relationships so it can handle all the storing for you.

Comment: self init will give call to init implementation in super class. Is there any other way by which I can store  array of ManagedObject into another managedObject?

Comment: You'll probably want to just use Core Data relationships. It's not exactly an array, but a simple fetch request will get you an `NSSet`, which you can convert to an NSArray. If order matters, you can even use `NSOrderedSet`.

Comment: If I change the accessor type of properties from "@dynamic" to "@synthesis", than it does not crash, but thats not the solution. I want to keep properties "@dynamic"

Comment: You are correct;  it won't end well.  The whole point of CoreData is to manage complex graphs of NSManagedObjects in a schema that you model.  That includes relationships that fully encompass array like containment. OP should use a "one to many" relationship to model one entity having a relationship to many of another entity.

Comment: I used one to many relationship,it has made things more easier to access and understand

Comment: @iVishal  Excellent!!  In general, if you find yourself fighting the frameworks, it is because you are going against the recommended patterns of use.  Finding something that should be easy to be quite difficult?  Take a step back and review the conceptual guides.   I've been at this (ObjC against the NeXT derived APIs) for nearly 25 years, and I still read the conceptual guides regularly.  Especially with each new OS release.

Comment: @bbum "if you find yourself fighting the frameworks, it is because you are going against the recommended patterns of use."==> very useful comment . I am glad to that I got some very useful and powerful suggestions from such experienced  developer. I have been following you on SO from long back. Your answers really help.